# Not enough memory for JVM heap when calling jni from dynamic library

Tags: java, c++, dll, jvm, java-native-interface

I have strange situation: we have .dll library (lets call it 'sdk_wrapper'), which is wrapper for java classes, which are opening JRE jvm.dll and use some other .dlls (PKCS11 implementations, to be more specific - but I think it doesn't matter).

Everything works fine when I use sdk_wrapper directly in my c++ program (alias 'run_dll'). But when I pack it into another .dll (to prepare configurations file, initialize library, etc) and export one function which is dong everything the same as program 'run_dll', calling this causes jvm initialization error: `Could not reserve enough space for object heap`. JVM.dll initialization is doing with `-Xmx512m`.

Have you any idea what's going on? I readed that JVM needs continous part of memory to initialize, but what's the difference between calling 'sdk_wrapper' directly from program and from another dll? They are at the same place (I mean in the same directory).

Answer (score 1):

As you load libraries into a memory, you end of with memory fragmentation of the address space. Win32 is particularly bad for this.

Note: if you use a 64-bit process this isn't an issue as you will have plenty of virtual memory.

Comment: Ok, so what is the difference between loading a.dll, which calls java, and loading b.dll, which loads a.dll, which calls java?

Comment: Each DLL you load uses some memory and might be loaded in a sub-optimal location. The JVM need continuous memory for the heap which is a problem for Windows it tends to fragment it's virtual address space.

Comment: Yes, I get it - but why loading `sdk_wrapper` directly from `.exe` doesn't cause error, when loading it from another `.dll` does?

Comment: @rzysia You would have to ask MS why they designed the OS the way they did. However I suspect even they don't know because when they implemented 64-bit they didn't do this. If you use a 64-bit JVM and DLLs you won't have this problem.

Comment: It becomes more strange now - when I'm using jre8, it works, but with older jre, it fails. 
I can't use 64bit .dll in this particular situation, but I can use jre8, so now everything works fine.
Thanks for your help, anyway :)